# Splitting data when object of study are correlated (based on "origin" group)

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, train-test-split, churn, data-leakage

everyone!

Imagine I have a dataset which I'd like to use it to train a churn model (fot example: logistic regression, xgboost binary classifier, lgbm binary classifier, etc.).

The structure of my available data is similar to the one below, where *Feature1,Feature2,...,FeatureN* are just placeholders for the real features.

[image]

When splitting the data into train,validation and test sets, I think I can't simply split it with train_test split functions (like the one in sklearn), because for each Company ID, I have multiple instances based on the year/month, and for each year/month the Churn result can be different (and so do the features), but all the instances within **ID a** are somehow correlated and splitting them between train and test would result in data leakage. Thus, i guess the right way to split the data is based on the whole ID, trying to sample the same proportion of IDs which had churn=1 in all train/test/val datasets.

Is that the correct way to approach this problem? And what if I'd like to perform a cross-validation with multiple folds, how to define this split logic based on the ID origin and not only on the % of the split?

Thank you in advance!